# How to generate getters and setters in NetBeans 11.0

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-11

I am trying to generate getters and setters or constructor or even methods that come from implemented interface, but I do not get anything. I have tried Alt + Enter, but nothing happens. Tried Alt + i, but when I did that I get only three options like: Connection to Database, Database Table and Action and/or Render Method. I feel like I use cutted version, although I got it from the official site of netbeans. What should I do? I got this only because I thought it will have improvements compared to the stable 8.2, but I get this and not all the plugins I got in 8.2. Should I install something else too to it or? I installed the binary version not the source version.

Link to the image when I press Alt + Ins: https://pasteboard.co/IlbSMDv.png
Link to the image of the plugins tab(most of them are activated, all php related are activated): https://pasteboard.co/IlbUolB.png

Comment: [1] Can you show a screen shot of the class that is giving the problem after you press ALT/INSERT (or even better, show a simplified version of the class if possible). Note that the context menu options shown are constrained by the content of your class file source. [2] What happens if you position the cursor anywhere within the class and just right-click the mouse instead? Does a context menu appear? [3] You may need to activate the plugins.  Go to **Tools > Plugins > Installed**, check **Show Details** and see if the plugin(s) you want to use are installed but not activated.

Comment: @skomisa I have activated some plugins(PHP ones mainly), but I get the same thing. I will add a picture now.

Answer (score 1):

To get the context menu working for a PHP class in Apache NetBeans 11.0:

- Activate all the PHP plugins:

  - **Tools > Plugins > Installed**.
  - Click **Show details** then sort by **Category**.
  - Scroll down, check all the plugins for the **PHP** category and click **Activate**. (Obviously you don't need to activate all the plugins; I just used that approach for simplicity.)

    [image: phpPlugins]
- Create a PHP project using the project wizard.
- Create a class for the PHP project using the project wizard.
- Postion the cursor anywhere within the class, and press ALT+INSERT. You will still see the problem you described in the OP: no getter/setter menu options are presented.
- Restart NetBeans, and try again. The menu options are now available:

  [image: phpContextMenu]

If you just restart NetBeans I think your context menu should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`Alt+Insert` opens the context menu you are looking for.

**Note**: `Alt+Insert` where you would put the new code
(i.e. `Alt+Insert` on empty line of the code inside the class) 
So don't put `Alt+Insert` when you are on **attribute** because *"getters and setters"* won't be shown

Comment: It does not. I was not gonna add possible duplicate if I saw the answer elsewhere. Alt + Insert opens only 3 options: Connection to Database, Database Table and Action and/or Render Method.

Comment: Yes it is on focus, I click on property then I press Alt + Ins and those are the only options I am provided with.